# Book page appears in one language (of four) only

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I run [a Drupal 7 site](http://balkan-preferans.de) with 4 languages installed: English (for me as admin) and 3 balkan languages (I don't speak them actually): Serbian, Croatian, Slovenian.

I have added [a book](http://balkan-preferans.de/en/node/1) there (url shortcut should be: `help`) and have added 3 book pages: Imprint (in German, url shortcut `imprint`), Privacy and Terms of Services (both pages have English content and url shortcuts `privacy` and `tos`).

**All 3 book pages should be visible in all languages - i.e. in English, Serbian, Croatian, Slovenian.**

However for some reason they are only visible in the Croatian view of my web site and also only `/hr/shortcuts` work.

And when I look at http://balkan-preferans.de/en/node/1#overlay=en/admin/content they have Croatian as language:

[image]

Can I somehow change the language to be **All**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found that setting under

```
Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » URL aliases
```

[image]

Or go to Modules and configure Path module settings

Setting the language to **All languages** has solved my problem